# Why this code isn't accepting a character input?

Tags: c, char, structure

I created a structure `Student` for storing name, age and gender of a student.
While accepting inputs for gender my program doesn't accepts the input (gender-'M' or 'F') which is of `char` datatype.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Student
{
    char name [25];
    int age;
    char gender;
};

struct Student stud[5];
int i;

void ask()
{
    for (i = 0; i<=5; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter details of student %d:",i+1);
        printf("\nEnter name: ");
        scanf("%s", stud[i].name);
        printf("\nEnter age: ");
        scanf("%d",&stud[i].age);
        printf("\nEnter gender: ");
        scanf("%c",&stud[i].gender);
    }
    printf("\nDisplaying student record:\n");
    for(i = 0; i<=5; i++)
    {
        printf("\nStudent name is: ",stud[i].name);
        printf("\nAge is: ",stud[i].age);
        printf("\nGender: ",stud[i].gender);
    }
}

void main()
{
    ask();
}
```

I expected the output as:

```
Enter the details of student1:
Enter Name: xyz
Enter age: 20
Enter gender: F
Enter the details of student2:
```

but the actual output is:

```
Enter the details of student1:
Enter Name: xyz
Enter age: 20
Enter gender:
Enter the details of students2:
Enter name:
```

Comment: Use  scanf(" %c",&stud[i].gender); See space between " and % symbols.

Comment: You should always check the return value of your `scanf` calls.

Comment: By the way, I think `i <= 5` isn't right in the for-loop.
Maybe `i < 5`?